Stabilizing ODELAY_VALUE related to IODELAY2 module in Spartan6 SLX9 FPGA Design for SDRAM Interface
I'm working on an FPGA design for the Spartan6 SLX9, which includes a memory controller for off-chip Micron SDRAM. To introduce a delay on the clock signal to the SDRAM relative to the Data/Command bus, I'm using an IODELAY2 with an ODELAY_VALUE to set the delay amount. The issue is that altering any unrelated part of my code impacts the ODELAY_VALUE. For instance, it works correctly with a value of 120, but any unrelated code change causes the SDRAM read operation to fail, requiring me to find a new ODELAY_VALUE. Interestingly, the same code works with a different ODELAY_VALUE in another project on the same board. How can I stabilize the ODELAY_VALUE regardless of other code changes?

Have you put any timing constraints on the clock output - specifically set_output_delay constraints? Without the constraints the synthesis tools are free to do whatever they want in routing the clock. With the constraints it will try harder to meet the delay requirements and be more consistent

@TomCarpenter While I'm using IODELAY2  for applying delay, is it necessary to use  set_output_delay constraints?

Yes, constraints are necessary. Contrary to what the name of the constraints suggests, it doesn't actually set any delays, but rather tells the timing tools about the requirements for the signal to meet timing. If the requirements are not met, it works harder when routing to meet them. If they still aren't met, that is when you start applying ODELAY values to help it meet timing if possible. But because it's already worked so hard in the routing stage, not much can change compile to compile so things are more stable. The timing tools can then tell you it will/won't work without hardware tests.

@TomCarpenter I tried adding constraints in my UCF file in ISE. This is the constraint: NET "sdram_clk" OFFSET = OUT 3.33 ns AFTER "CLK_RAM"; CLK_RAM is the source clock that I apply delay on and it has been generated from my main clock with a clocking wizard IP core. In this situation, I get a warning in the translation report: "This constraint will be ignored because NET "CLK_RAM" could not be found or was not connected to a PAD." Should I connect any net I want to set constraints on it to a pad?
